# How does chain rule work for complex valued function?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Formally we have the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule):
$$(f\circ g)'(x)= (f'\circ g) \cdot g'$$

Let $f:\mathbb R^{3} \to \mathbb C$ and $g:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ be nice functions. Then does it make sense to talk that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial {x_1}} (g\circ f)(x)= (g'\circ f(x)) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} f(x), (*)$$ where $x=(x_1, x_2, x_3)$   and $g'(z)=\frac{d}{dz} g(z), z\in \mathbb C$ (complex derivative)

Note that we are mixing complex derivative  first and  at the end  partial derivative.

> **My Question**: (1)Is the above formula true? Does it make to sense to talk of the above  $(*)$ formula? And what should  be the multiplication  $\cdot $ in the formula ? (2) Suppose now  we consider $g$ as function of $z$ and $\bar{z}$ (eg. $g(z)=z^{2} \bar{z}^3$). Does it make sense to talk that $\frac{\partial}{\partial {x_1}} (g\circ f)(x)= (g'\circ f(x)) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} f(x),$ where $x=(x_1, x_2, x_3)$  and  wghat should be $\cdot $ ?, and $g'(z)=\frac{\partial}{\partial z} g(z), z\in \mathbb C$ (complex derivative)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is perfectly ok if by $g$ 'nice' you mean complex differentiable. If we restrict to the derivative in the direction $e_1$ then for $h$ (real and) small:
$$ f(x+he_1)=f(x)+\partial_1f(x)h +o(h)$$
Since also (complex derivative)
$$ g(z+\delta z) = g(z) + g'(z) \delta z+ o(\delta z)$$
we get (for the last you should do some 'little-o' estimate):
  $$g(f(x+he_1))= g(f(x) + \partial_1 f(x) h + o(h)) = g(f(x)) + g'(f(x)) \partial_1 f(x) h + o(h)$$
from which you can read off the precise formula (*) that you have stated.

If $g$ is a function of both $z$ and $\bar{z}$ then you get two terms, one from each partial derivative of $g$ + some complex conjugation. One has
$$ g(z+\delta z) = g(z) + \partial_z g(z) \delta z+ \partial_{\bar{z}} g(z) \overline{\delta z} + o(\delta z)$$
and the derivative of the composed function becomes:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} (g(f(x))) = \partial_z g(f(x)) \partial_1 f(x) + \partial_{\bar{z}} g(f(x)) \overline{\partial_1 f(x)}$$

For example, with $g(z)=z\; \bar{z}=|z|^2$ we have $$|z+\delta z|^2-|z|^2 = z \; \overline{\delta z} +  \overline{z}  \;\delta z \;+ o(\delta z)$$

Comment: Thanks: Are you saying $\frac{\partial}{\partial {x_1}} (g\circ f)(x)= (g'\circ f(x)) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} f(x),$  is correct? Even if we consider $g'(z)= \frac{\partial}{\partial z}(g )$?

Comment: Yes, that's fine when $g$ is complex differentiable.

Comment: Thanks: I am keen to understand the last inequality. Can you explain me bit further? Is this follows from the formula $(*)$?

Comment: Why complex conjugation comes?

Comment: @HHR:Thanks a lot: I am willing to know: how $ g(z+\delta z) = g(z) + \partial_z g(z) \delta z+ \partial_{\bar{z}} g(z) \overline{\delta z} + o(\delta z)$ ?

Comment: How does this follows?

Comment: In this context, $g(z)$ is a 'shorthand' notation for $g(z,\bar{z})$. You may then develop $g(z+\delta z, \bar{z}+\overline{\delta z})-g(z,\bar{z})$ as a function of two variables. Does this make sense? You may try it out on $z\bar{z}$